# Validate and get django form's unkown number of multipleselect checkbox fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, checkboxlist

I am trying to get all selected checkboxes values as a list however not able to validate the form due to choices option

forms.py:

```
class MarkAccountsForm(forms.Form):
    accounts = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required = False
    )
```

template:

```
{% for account in accounts %}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="accounts" value="{{ account.id }}"></td>
        <td>{{ account.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MarkAccountsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): #this fails
        data = form.cleaned_data
```

When I try to print `form.errors`, it says `Select a valid choice. 1119 is not one of the available choices.`

Is there a way that I can avoid choice validation and still get values of all accounts checkboxes checked as a list? How do I say it to allow any for choices? If I can get the list without form validation then that is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about validation, why are you calling `is_valid`? In fact, why are you using a Form class at all? You're not using it to display the form, so you might as well leave it out altogether and just get the data from `request.POST.getlist('accounts')`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, was wondering when you'd reply. Well avoiding `is_valid` was my secondary option incase if it cant be done, and I did not know about `getlist`, i tried `get` and it only gave me last ticked checkbox's id.